# Postfixでパイプを使ってphpを実行する。

Tags: postfix

お世話になります。

Postfixでパイプを使ってphpを実行する設定を行っております。
何か足りないものがあるのでしょうか？
ご教授のほどお願いします
（以前別の環境で設定したところうまくいきました）

---

環境
Linux CentOS 6.6
Postfix 2.6.6

1.
master.cfにプログラム起動のパイプ処理を追加する。
参考で下記のように行いました

```
webmaster-test unix    -       n       n       -       - pipe
  flags=R user=vmailuser argv=/usr/bin/php -f /tmp/test.php $sender
```

2.
transportでパイプに渡すメールアドレスを追加する。

```
webmaster@***.com     webmaster-test
```

これでwebmaster@***.comにメールを送信すると/tmp/test.phpが実行されると思うのですが実行されません。

### name@sample.com→webmaster@***.comに送ったときのmaillogです。smtpのところにdisconnectと出ていますが、送受信はできています。

Jun 10 22:54:30 shcnwq postfix/smtpd[1624]: connect from www937.sakura.ne.jp[219.94.128.177]
Jun 10 22:54:30 shcnwq postfix/smtpd[1624]: A3077A4DB2: client=www937.sakura.ne.jp[219.94.128.177]
Jun 10 22:54:30 shcnwq postfix/cleanup[1637]: A3077A4DB2: message-id=<55784197.1030006@sample.com>
Jun 10 22:54:30 shcnwq postfix/qmgr[1402]: A3077A4DB2: from=, size=1376, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 10 22:54:30 shcnwq postfix/virtual[1639]: A3077A4DB2: to=, relay=virtual, delay=0.18, delays=0.15/0.03/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Jun 10 22:54:30 shcnwq postfix/qmgr[1402]: A3077A4DB2: removed
Jun 10 22:54:30 shcnwq postfix/smtpd[1624]: disconnect from www937.sakura.ne.jp[219.94.128.177]

Comment: maillogではどのようなログが出ていますか。質問を編集して追記してください。

Comment: 返信有難うございました、追記しました

Answer (score 1):

次のいずれかではないかと思います。

1. main.cf の transport_maps パラメータが transport ファイルを参照していない
2. postmap コマンドで transport ファイルをDB化していない
3. postmap コマンド実行後に postfix reload していない